# I'm getting Cast to ObjectID failed for value "shopping-cart" at path "_id" for model "Product" in NodeJS mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

so I have a /shopping-cart route and it works fine but if I add another route (get route of /:id), it gives me the error that is mentioned in title.

This is the /shopping-cart route:

```
router.get("/shopping-cart", (req,res)=>{
  
  if(!req.session.cart) return res.redirect("/");
  let xcart= new Cart(req.session.cart);
  res.render("shopping-cart", {products: xcart.generateArray(), totalPrice: xcart.totalPrice, qty: xcart.qty, totalQty: xcart.totalQty})
  
});
```

Now, this above route works fine but when I create another route (code below) it gives me the error mentioned in the title. Here's the code:

```
router.get("/:id", asyncMiddlewareHandler(async(req,res)=>{
  let id= req.params.id;
  let pproduct= await Product.findById(id);
  console.log(pproduct);
  res.render("product",{product:pproduct});
}))
```

I don't understand why using this route causes an error in that route. Can anybody help me fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Try to use search, there's a lot of question like yours https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+cast+Objectid

Comment: Just realized that the error means that the value of id you are passing to the `Product.findById` is `shopping-cart` so your problem is that the route `router.get("/:id"` also handles `router.get("/shopping-cart"` so you may want to change the route to something like `router.get("/shopping-cart/:id"`  It is always a good idea to `console.log(id)` to see what you are passing to the `findbyId`

Comment: @Molda what do you mean that thr route also handles shopping-cart route? could you elaborate please?

Comment: Just try to `console.log(id)` before this line `let pproduct= await Product.findById(id);` and you will see that the id is `shopping-cart`. It means when you request `/shopping-cart` it is processed by `router.get("/:id"` and not by `router.get("/shopping-cart"`

Comment: btw, I have changed the route and it is working now.. Still, I don't understand how router.get("/:id") was also handling router.get("/shopping-cart")

Comment: Well it is obvoius that `/shopping-cart` matches `/:id`. In your code do you have `router.get("/:id"` above `router.get("/shopping-cart"`? If so try to move it bellow. The order is important. Althought i would recommend to use `router.get("/shopping-cart/:id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`shopping-cart` string can not be used as value for finding the document since `findById()` only accept value of type `ObjectId` .

Solution: Make sure `req.params.id` is always documents `_id` otherwise it will consider it as a string and will throw error

While finding `Product.findById(id)` id has to be of type ObjectId

```
router.get("/:id", asyncMiddlewareHandler(async(req,res)=>{
  let id= req.params.id; // req.params.id = 'shopping-cart'
  let pproduct= await Product.findById(id); // accepts _id of type as saved in document for _id
  console.log(pproduct);
  res.render("product",{product:pproduct});
}))
```

Example:

- `/shopping-cart` api won't work
- `/5e85ba9c8467e208597bbfc8` will work fine